# If F followed by Fm resolves to C, What do F# and F#m resolve to?

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-progressions

Firstly, apologies if I am using the wrong terminology here. I am a beginner guitarist and only know a little music theory.

Considering the example of 'I will Follow you into the Dark' by Death Cab For Cutie, the introduction features the progression:

> Am, C, E, Am, G, F, Fm, C/G

Messing around on the fretboard, I realised that I can play those same F barre chords on the second fret which presumably are `F#` and `F#m`.

So what what would naturally follow in that case and be the 'resolving chord' instead of C/G? And why?

Comment: It depends on the context and key.  If you're subbing those two chords straight into that song it isn't going to work regardless.  If you're transposing everything up ... transpose *everything* up.

Comment: I'm not doing that. I just played the same barre chords one fret up and wondered what the next chord would be if I did transpose everything...

Comment: It can resolve to whatever you want, if you make it.

Comment: Two more songs with this resolution are Till there was you, and In my life. I always thought the D-Dm-A was John's genius at work, till I realized Till there was you, a song the Beatles covered, had that same progression in a different key.

Comment: I repeat: +1. To the remover of my comments: I do not appreciate having my voice removed from the forum. I **will** let it be known that I **do** think this is a good question and that I most definitely *do* disagree with any downvoters, regardless of their opinion of the question's integrity. To wit: I am *not at all* a beginner musician (15+ years of dedicated improvement), though I don't know as much about theory as I would like to, and this question and it's answers has proved useful to me ...

Comment: but, *more importantly*, I have a distinct proclivity to think other beginner musicians might have the same question and, further, that they will learn something here. If it is a duplicate, please indicate so; or otherwise flag it as a poor question with either your downvote or a community-accepted mehod of doing so. **Please do not make the mistake that your sacrosanct opinion regarding the quality of a question coincides with that of the learners of the community, and, especially, that it is somehow more important.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C#.   Because it's the same thing, shifted up a semi-tone.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Looks like C# is a harder chord for a beginner which is probably why I haven't been exposed to it yet. http://chord-c.com/guitar-chord/C/sharp-major/

Comment: Doesn't look any "harder" than F or Fm to me?

Comment: @LaurencePayne It is harder to finger an A-shaped barre chord than an E-shaped one. And a C-shaped barre is rarely even fingered across 6 strings because it's more finger-bending.

Comment: @AJFaraday Your opinion that it is harder to finger an A-shaped barre chord is just that - an opinion! Also, I play C-shaped barre chords across all 6 strings *more often than not* (although technically it's an inversion of the root chord, I suppose). Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in fact **"C#/G#"** (a C# with a G# as the bass note).  That chord can be played as an A shaped barre chord on the 4th fret (446664).

But playing the progression - **Am, C, E, Am, G, F, Fm, C/G** a semitone higher will mean having to play **all barre chords** instead of the open Am, E, and G and C/G.

Not sure why you would want to do that.  If your desire is to play the song in a key one half step higher, my solution would be to put a capo on the first fret and play the same (mostly open) chord shapes.  Unless you would rather play barre chords.  I personally try to only play barre chords when there is a good reason or a need.  Otherwise I avoid barre chords.

Just sayin .....

Answer (score 2):

The progression F - Fm - C/G is a technique used in many songs.  The F is the IV of C. The walk down is in the third of the F chord (A) to F Minor (Ab) then to the C Major (G), there is a G bass note over the C chord.  So their is a chromatic movement of A-Ab-G in the harmony.
'Wake Me Up When September Ends' uses this over the hook in the song. It is used in all forms of music for a smooth transition to the I chord.

To answer the question you would resolve to the C# chord. What you are hearing is that popular movement at the end of the progression.